# Regex - Match lines that contain at least 2 vowels

Tags: regex, computer-science, regular-language

I want to find all lines that contain at least two vowels.

I tried to use the sentence: .*[aeiou].{2,}\n
But it seems that it doesn't succeed, in this failed result it still contains even lines with only one vowel such as "abc123"[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rgZHW.png)

Comment: Of course not, with `.{2,}` you are saying that you want any arbitrary character (that's what the dot stands for), at least two times. And the character class `[aeiou]` only demands for _one_ of those, since you did not put any quantifier behind it.

Comment: You want `.*[aeiou].*[aeiou].*` - a vowel, then any number (including zero) of arbitrary characters, and then a vowel again.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what your definition of a sentence is, but the following matches two vowels each followed by anything (even other vowels).

([aeiou].*){2}

Answer (score 0):

What about something as simple as `.*[aeiou].*[aeiou]`?

Your `{2,}` applies to the dot just before.

Comment: i just tried this, but still not work. i finally use ([aeiou].*){2}  and it works now

Comment: oh it works! i left a * at the end. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to match the whole line, you can use a negated character class to prevent backtracking:

```
^(?:[^aeiou\n]*[aeiou]){2}.*
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `(?:` Non capture group to repeat as a whole part

  - `[^aeiou\n]*[aeiou]` Optionally repeat matching any char except the listed or a newline followed by matching one of `a` `e` `i` `o` `u`
- `){2}` Close the non capture group and repeat it 2 times
- `.*` Match the rest of the line

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/HBlIKs/1)